# how to use json_encode without PHP 5.2

Tags: php, ajax, json

I've written a CMS which uses the PHP function json_encode to send some data back via an Ajax Request.

Unfortunately, I'm trying to load it onto a server which is running PHP version 5.1, the json_encode PHP function is not available on versions of PHP before 5.2.0.

Does anyone know of a way to encode a PH array as JSON without using the inbuilt json_encode function?

**EDIT**

I've used Pekka's function, but now I find JQuery won't parse the result as expected. Even though Firebug shows JSON being passed back through. My firebug window looks like this:[image]

and my jquery looks like this:

```
     $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "includes/function/add_users.php",
            data: str,
            dataType: 'json',
            cache: false,
            beforeSend: function(html){
                    $('#editbox').html('<img class="preloader" src="images/ajax-loader.gif"/>');
            },

            success: function(html){
                fields = html;
                $('#div1').html(fields['username']);
                $('#div2').html(fields['fname']);
```

But the divs : #div1 and #div2 will not load the correct data.

**FOR WHY?**

Comment: I assume you have closed the ajax statement correctly? closing both the success function and then the overall ajax function?

Comment: yes, they were properly closed, I just included the relevant part of the code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The User Contributed Notes to [json_encode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php#89908) have a number of implementations. On a cursory glance, [this one](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php#89908) looks the best to me.

If you have access to PECL, I would use the extension as @Artefacto recommends.

Comment: OK that works fine - firebug shows JSON being passed. However Jquery doesn't like it...

Comment: Ok - see the extended question above

Comment: @Ashley you will need to show some actual JSON so we can tell what's wrong with it. Alternatively, @Mark Baker's suggestion looks interesting as well.

Comment: @Ashley isn't the JSON result an Object? Meaning you need to use `fields.username`?

Comment: A new implementation has been proposed on User Contributed Notes, seems quite good too. Deserves a try: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php#107968

Answer (score 1):

I hit up the google...
This person has made a encoder of their own:

http://www.post-hipster.com/2008/02/15/elegant-little-php-json-encoder/

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [PECL extension](http://pecl.php.net/package/json).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`json_encode` for earlier versions of PHP 5.x](http://www.boutell.com/scripts/jsonwrapper.html) if you are using an older version of PHP. It works great!